# Mass rename in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, rename, git-bash

I have a bunch of files which are of this format:

```
blabla.log.YYYY.MM.DD
```

Where `YYYY.MM.DD` is something like (`2016.01.18`)

I have quite a few folders with about 1000 files in each, so I wanted to have a simple script to rename them. I want to rename them to

```
blabla.log
```

So basically, I'm just stripping the date at the end. Here is what I have:

```
for f in [a-zA-Z]*.log.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]; do 
    mv -v $f ${f#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]}; 
done
```

This script outputs this:

```
mv: `blabla.log.2016.01.18' and `blabla.log.2016.01.18' are the same file
```

For more information:

- I'm on windows, but I run this script in gitbash
- For some reason, my gitbash doesn't recognize the "rename" command
- Some regex patterns (like `[0-9]{4}` don't seem to work)

I'm really at a lost. Thanks.

EDIT: I need to rename every single file that has a date at the end and that is of the from: *.log.2016.01.18. They all need to keep their original names. All that should change is the removal of the date.

Comment: Do you want to rename all as `blabla.log`??? Precise your need please.

Comment: `${f%.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]}`: extra `.` and `%` instead of `#`

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked just like I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `%` instead of `#`: you want to remove from the end, not the start of your string.

Also, you're missing a `.` in what has to be removed, you don't want to end up with `blabla.log.`.

Quoting the variable names prevents surprises when file names contain special characters.

Together:

```
mv -v "$f" "${f%.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]}"
```